# Removing the view controller from memory after logging out?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode7

I have a collection view of cells that scroll horizontally. Every time I log out, my main view controller gets dismissed to the log in screen. But when I log back in, it seems that my main view controller was never removed from memory. I say this because my collection view cells are in the same position as they were before I logged out.

I tried everything, from viewWillAppear and reloading the data, to trying to bring my log in view controller as my root window. Any suggestions?

(To be clearly demonstrate this, when you log out of Instagram (from the settings view controller), a log-in view is presented modally. When you log back in, you are presented with the Home feed, instead of the settings view controller. I want to reset the hierarchy of data)

```
class MainController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let feedId = "feedId"

    var allUserCategory: AllUserCategory?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.pagingEnabled = true
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 250, g: 250, b: 250)
        collectionView?.registerClass(AllUserCategory.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: feedId)

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Log Out", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false

        checkIfUserLoggedIn()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    func handleLogout() {
        print("Logged out")
        do {
            try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()

        } catch let logoutError {
            print(logoutError)
        }

        allUserCategory?.users.removeAll()

        let loginController = LoginController()
        let loginNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginController)
        presentViewController(loginNav, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Best way to handle login flows is embedding them in a container view controller in such a way that only either the login flow or the main app is held in memory at any given time. Logging out thus releases the existing main app from memory when a new login flow is instantiated and embedded

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering! Do you think Instagram uses a container view when it modally presents the login view controller when you sign out?

Comment: Container views embed their children in place of modal presentation, similar to how navigation controllers work. I would suspect that Instagram and most professional applications follow this architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add NSLog in  dealloc

And maybe you have some memory leak in your code(MainViewController).

Answer (score 0):

Use weak reference for IBOutlet and custom delegate